# PaginatedList Search giving error when pageIndex > 0 on unique record in table C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, search, pagination

I am implementing search functionality on my index page that shows a list of records from a paginated list.

[Initial index view of records on when page loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggT9q.png)

The search function works for

1.) if search box value matches multiple records in table, it will go to the search view that shows the list of these records

2.) if user clicks types in a search that doesnt exist. User stays on current page and an error message pops up

3.) if user clicks search while textbox is empty then appropriate error message pops up on current page.

**ISSUE**

4.) If user types in a search that returns one record, retuning this one record while staying in current view **ONLY WORKS** if one has not scrolled through the list.. i.e if I navigate to page 1,2,3 etc then search for a unique record I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
But if one is on a fresh instance of the page (I am viewing forst record on the list), I can search for any unique record that exists and it will be loaded into the view.

url while on first record/page (for search that works)
- localhosturl/Product?page=0
or
- localhosturl/Product

url while not on first page (for search that doesnt work)
- Product?page=1  .. page=2, page=3 etc
in which I get object reference not set error

```
        int pageSize = 1;
        var currentPageIndex = page ?? 0;
        PageIndex = currentPageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;

        //string currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter;
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        //keep current page state(number) during update/save
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

        var viewModelQuery = (from c in db.q_product.AsEnumerable()
                              orderby c.q_barcode
                              select new ProductViewModel
                              {
                                  //viewModel properties
                              });

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            viewModelQuery = viewModelQuery.Where(s => s.q_description.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper().Trim())
            || s.q_barcode.Contains(searchString.Trim()));                

            searchCount = viewModelQuery.Count();

            if (searchCount > 1)
            {
                //if more than one record in query 
                //we want to show the list of this search (on a different page)
                TempData["String"] = searchString.Trim();
                return RedirectToAction("Search", new { id = searchString });                    
            }
            if (searchCount == 0)
            {
                //if no record was found in query
                //lets stay on current page and return "not found" message
                TempData["NoRecordMessage"] = "Record not found!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = page });
            }                
        }

        var pagedProduct = new PaginatedList<ProductViewModel>(viewModelQuery, currentPageIndex, pageSize);            

        //Lets populate our dropdown lists            
        ViewBag.department_guid = new SelectList(db.q_department, "department_guid", "q_name", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().department_guid);
        ViewBag.q_subdepartmentid = new SelectList(db.q_subdepartment, "department_guid", "q_subdepartmentname", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().q_subdepartmentid);
        ViewBag.q_groupid = new SelectList(db.q_group, "q_groupid", "q_groupname", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().q_groupid);
        ViewBag.q_measuretype = new SelectList(db.q_unitofmeasure, "q_measuretype", /*"UnitNameAndValue",*/ "q_unit", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().q_measuretype);
        ViewBag.vat_guid = new SelectList(db.q_vat, "vat_guid", "q_rate", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().vat_guid);

        if (searchString == "" || (searchCount > 0 && searchString.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            //if user clicked search button without text on search box
            //stay on current page and return "no search" message
            TempData["EmptySearch"] = "No search found!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = page });
        }

        if (searchCount == 1)
        {
            //we have found 1 record in list
            TempData["UniqueRecord"] = "1 record found!";                
            return View(pagedProduct);
        }

        //otherwise show default paginatedList on page load
        return View(pagedProduct);
```

So How can I make the unique record search work if I have navigated through the pages / list?

**Additional Info: 08/06/17**
Issue is probably to do with current page index and skip method in the paginatedList class. When I remove .Skip(PageIndex * PageSize) from this line (in different class file) PaginatedList.cs

```
    this.AddRange(viewModelQuery.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
```

search for unique product works perfectly fine, but records do not scroll to the next item on list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for anyone that might find themselves with a similar issue. It was indeed a page index issue, after going through this link

[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-a-search-box-to-the-students-index-page)

> If the search string is changed during paging, the page has to be reset to 1, because the new filter can result in different data to display. The search string is changed when a value is entered in the text box and the submit button is pressed. In that case, the searchString parameter is not null.

so all I need to add was this if statement

```
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            //PageIndex has to be reset, if searchstring is changed during paging (user not on first page)
            //This avoids "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when 
            //on page 1,2,3.... etc
            currentPageIndex = 0;
            PageIndex = currentPageIndex;
        }
```